# PHP form confirmation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I’m having trouble with my form and I don’t know what to do.
I'm creating a form to collect the data and pass it to a second page (name, username, password...) When I fill my first form I have all the validation errors that it should have but it still let me go to the next page(for example if in the first page I enter name: sara the second page would say welcome sara. Normally if its empty it shouldn't go to the second but in my case it does. How can I force to fill all information and validate password before going to the next page?

Thank you.

```
<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $Name       = $_POST['Name'];
    $lastName   = $_POST['lastName'];
    $userName   = $_POST['userName'];
    $pWord      = $_POST['pWord'];
    $confirm    = $_POST['confirm'];
      
          if(empty($Name) || empty($lastName) || empty($userName) || empty($pWord) || empty($confirm)){
            $empty_error = "Enter all informations";
              include('Registration.php');
        }
  

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that redirects to the next page?

Comment: <label> <h2>Create your  account </h2></label>
  <form action="Process.php" method="post" > I'm very new at web dev and from my unserstanding i need to just enter the php page in action to get there

Comment: If the first `if` evaluates as true, your `else if (...)` won't be executed or even evaluated. so you can't use variables you defined in `if () {....}` in the `else if (...)`. You need to create another separate `if`-statement to verify them, or add `empty($_POST['Name']) || ...` in the first `if`. [Here's the manual about else/else if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Not seeing the logic of your `else if`. E.g. wouldn't you expect your `create` field to exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have bad condition.

You need to checked if variables are empty inside the IF, not in the else branch (your ELSE IF meant *if !isset($_POST['create'])* - and in that case all variables are undefined).

```
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $Name       = $_POST['Name'];
    $lastName   = $_POST['lastName'];
    $userName   = $_POST['userName'];
    $pWord      = $_POST['pWord'];
    $confirm    = $_POST['confirm'];

    if(empty($Name) || empty($lastName) || empty($userName) || empty($pWord) || empty($confirm)){
        // at least one field is empty
        $empty_error = "Enter all informations";
        include('Registration.php');
    } else {
        // all data are filled, do stuff
    }
}
```